# population growth with parabolic growth ratio

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am reading a book about modelling Complex System and on chapter 4 the following logistic growth model is presented:
$$
f(x) = -\frac{a-1}{K}x+a
$$
$$
x_{t} = f(x_{t-1})x_{t-1}
$$
where $f(x)$ is the function that controls the growth ratio.

The book presents an exercise which says:

*Create a mathematical model of population growth in which the
growth ratio is highest at a certain optimal population size, but it goes down as the
population deviates from the optimal size*

and it suggests to use a different $f(x)$, for example an upper convex parabola that has its peak at the optimal population size $x_{op}$

Would anyone be willing to suggest me a solution?